# What does "sq" mean when referencing page or verse numbers?

Tags: meaning, abbreviations

In the book I am reading (Patrick Fairbairn, *The Interpretation of Prophecy*, 2nd ed., 1865), the abbreviation "sq." is used sometimes in referencing both Scripture and other books (as "Typology of Scripture, vol. i. p. 100 sq." or "Ezek xxvi. 7, sq."). What does "sq." mean in this context?

(Instances of this abbreviation's usage may be found at Google Books [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=uV_OAAAAMAAJ&pg=PR1#v=onepage&q=sq&f=false).)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Sq.* is short for the Latin word *sequiturque*, which means **the following**.

So *p. 100 sq.* means **page 100 and those following pages**.

Here's the [source](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sq.).

Comment: I would have guessed "and subsequent."  +1 for getting the Latin!

Comment: FYI: I think it's more common today to write "ff" for "following", as in, "p. 100 ff" meaning "page 100 and following". (Not diagreeing with your answer, just making a random observation.)

Comment: IMHO, 100 *sq* means 'pages 100 and 101'; '100 and the following pages' is 100 *sqq*. (Or, of course, *f* and *ff*.)

Answer (score 7):

Per MW:

> **sq**. [Latin *sequens*; *sequentes*; *sequentia*] the following

NB: *sequiturque* means "followed by a...," not "the following."